# Specify a Finder item by its path

Tags: applescript, finder

is it possible to specify a Finder item by its path?

e.g. I want to refresh the icon of a single item. So far, to do this, I call update on every item of the front window:

`tell application "Finder" to update every item in front window`

But this only works if the folder currently has the item. Is it possible to specify an item with its path, so that the update will work even if the item is not visible in Finder?

`tell application "Finder" to update item_x`

where `item_x` is the item i want to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure just give it an alias but then your hard coding it in there

```
   tell application "Finder" to update "path:to:your:file.ext"
```

of course there are many more approaches you can take for this it just depend on how you want to get the item(s) you could

have a script in your menu that asks for an item using choose file

have a script in your menu that asks for a folder using choose folder

maybe some other options I'm sure.. can you provide more information what the process is  ?

Comment: took your advice and it works. i generated the alias from the POSIX path of an item then passed it to `update`. but Finder doesn't seem to want to update the icon for any item that isn't currently visible (displayed onscreen). thanks for this, though. (i'm trying to refresh icons real-time when one is edited)

Comment: This is not working. When I give a command `osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to update "/Users/taran/somefolder/somefile.png"'`, I get this error: `29:69: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t make "/Users/taran/somefolder/somefile.png" into type item. (-1700)`

Comment: Never mind... adding `POSIX file` in front of the file worked.

Comment: @TarandeepGill glad you figured it out and hope my answer helped you :)